# How can I list which packages are from experimental?

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

I have a system which is a mishmash of testing and unstable and some from experimental.

How can I get a list of which packages I've installed from experimental?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I came up with this solution:

```
aptitude -t experimental search -F '%p %?V %?v %?t' --disable-columns .|\
grep -v none| \
grep experimental| \
awk '{if( $2 == $3) print $1}'
```

The `aptitude` line gets me a list with "package name(%p)", "version if upgrade to experimental(%?V)", "installed version(%?v)" and "archives(%?t)".

Then filter away packages which are not installed.

And keep only packages which are available in experimental.

If installed and upgradable version are the same we have a winner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aptitude search "~S~i~Aexperimental"`

Answer (score 0):

There might be an easy way to do that, but if there isn't this *might* work to get you close:

- Get all package names and versions from `dpkg --list`
- Comment out all sources but stable in your apt sources, and then `apt-get update`
- Search for all the installed package in the dpkg list, if it isn't there that is one. else use `--compare-versions` to dpkg to see if you have is newer than what is returned from apt.

I hope for your sake there is a better way ;-)

Comment: Oh, and if this is just because your system is all messed up, you might just want to start over.

Comment: My system works as it should. Just realized I had no idea how far from  unstable I'd gone.